# Pending changes window not coming VS2015 SVN

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2015, visualsvn

I am using svn for source control and all worked seamlessly but recently I see my pending changes window is not coming. I checked View->Other Windows there also Pending changes window is disabled I am attaching image of the same.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KjkO.png]

Comment: What SVN plug-in do you use in Visual Studio? Is it VisualSVN or AnkhSVN?

Comment: I am using VisualSVN 5.1.5. All was working good it suddenly stopped showing that window.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the VisualSVN Pending Changes window via <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> keyboard shortcut or via the main menu: **VisualSVN | Windows | Pending Changes**.